# How can I decrease the size of Thumbs.db files?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, database, thumbnails

I don't want to disable Thumbs.db files created by Windows, I just want to make the thumbnails be viewed in smaller size and even in worse quality. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: running out of HDD space? I've never seen those things more than 5mb max (1000's of photos) :P

Comment: Right :) My obsolete laptop's HDD is running out of space. That's one reason. The other is I like useful tweaks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **[Thumbnail Control](http://leelusoft.blogspot.com/2008/07/thumbnail-control.html)** you can set the size and quality of thumbnail for folders that contain pictures.

[image]

Just drag the track bars to high or low quality or to small or big size, click on Apply and now open a pictures folder and see the results.

Use the reset to default button to set the default configurations.

*Thumbnail Control is freeware and portable (doesn't require installation).*

With **[ThumbTweak](http://download.cnet.com/ThumbTweak/3000-2072_4-10433456.html)** you can change Windows Explorer's thumbnail view. Easily change your thumbnails size, and quality. Selecting from presets or creating your own. Quickly preview the size, then easily make the change. Install-free on Windows XP systems.

[image]

*ThumbTweak is freeware.*

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Comment: @Molly I'm curious as to know what were your search keywords!

Comment: @ Sathya: decrease thumbnail size